# unicode degree symbol from siunitx

Tags: siunitx, unicode, degrees

I'd like the unicode "degree sign" ° from siunitx's `\ang` and `\SI{10}{\celsius}`. But, from this code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\listfiles
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  text-degree=°,
  math-degree=\textup{°}
}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\ang{10} $10^\circ$
\SI{10}{\celsius}
\end{document}
```

I get the "white bullet" symbol ◦ both with lualatex and with pdflatex.
(You generate a PDF file from your LaTeX source, display it, copy the text, paste it to your text editor, and examine what symbol you have gotten.)

I use texlive 2021 and update it very often.

The following is the file list generate by the `\listfiles` command above:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 siunitx.sty    2022-01-05 v3.0.39 A comprehensive (SI) units package
translations.sty    2022/01/04 v1.11 internationalization of LaTeX2e packages (CN)
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
 ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
 amstext.sty    2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
l3keys2e.sty    2021-11-12 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
   expl3.sty    2021-11-22 L3 programming layer (loader)
l3backend-luatex.def    2021-12-14 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
   array.sty    2021/10/04 v2.5f Tabular extension package (FMi)
  ts1cmr.fd    2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
   color.sty    2021/12/07 v1.3c Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  luatex.def    2021/06/01 v1.2c Graphics/color driver for luatex
supp-pdf.mkii
translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl    (english translation file `translations-basic-dictionary')
 ***********
```

Comment: Please add `\listfiles` to your input and edit the resulting `File list` from your `.log` into the question

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for your help. Does that mean that you think this may be a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For v3, the options `text-degree`, etc., have been disabled (this will show in the log). You will need to re-declare the appropriate units:

```latex
\DeclareSIUnit[quantity-product = ]\degree{\text{°}}
\DeclareSIUnit\degreeCelsius{\text{°}C}
```